# how to insert the data from a text file to a python programme

Tags: python-3.x, mediawiki, jupyter

This is the exact code in python3 for a wikimedia project on [Jupyter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/PAWS)

```
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site('ta', 'wikisource')
page = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Index:தந்தை பெரியார் சிந்தனைகள்.pdf')
page.text = page.text.replace('பேராசிரியர் ந. சுப்புரெட்டியார்','மின்னூல்கள்-பொதுகள உரிமம்-த. இ. க. க. 2015')
page.save()
```

In the above code, i want to change the pdf name one by one from a text file(book-list) and finally,  i want to save. To save manually, i am using shif+enter. How to automate my cotributions?

Here is the example of pdf name as in text file namely book-list which is having more than 2200 pdfs.

```
Index:அகத்திணைக் கொள்கைகள்.pdf
Index:அண்ணல் அநுமன்.pdf
Index:அணுக்கரு பௌதிகம்.pdf
```

Comment: Finally, i wrote the code;-

Comment: https://github.com/neqkir/wikisource-scraper

Answer (score 0):

Finally i extended the above code as follows;-

```
import csv
import pywikibot
with open('list-book-parameters.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter="~")
    for row in reader:
      if len(row) == 8:
       if not 'booktitle' in row:   
        booktitle=row[0]
        #print (row[0]) 
        site = pywikibot.Site('ta', 'wikisource')
        page = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Index:' + booktitle + '.pdf')
        page.text = page.text.replace('old data','new data')
        page.save()
```

The data in the list-book-parameters.csv as follows;-

```
booktitle~version~publisher~press~date~place~coverpage~category
```

--solved myself ;)